# Change value of createdAt in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to set the value of `createdAt` to some time in the past.

However, all of my attempts fail to change the `createdAt` date in the database. The value remains the same.

```js
const yesterday = ( d => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)) )(new Date);

// failed attempts
hang.createAt = yesterday;
hang.set('createdAt', yesterday);
hang.changed('createdAt', yesterday);

await hang.save();
```

I also tried

```js
const yesterday = ( d => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)) )(new Date);

// failed attempt
await hang.update({ createdAt: yesterday });
```

Proof of issue

```js
2020-10-07T19:24:29.058Z // before
2020-10-07T19:24:29.058Z // after
```

*How can I change the `createdAt` value of an instance?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this

```
const yesterday = ( d => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)) )(new Date);

hang.changed('createdAt', true);
hang.set('createdAt', yesterday,{raw: true});
await hang.save({
        silent: true,
        fields: ['createdAt']
 });
```

from the documentation
[set :](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-set)

```
raw: true
```

> if a custom setter function is defined for the key, that function will be called instead. To bypass the setter, you can pass raw: true in the options object.

and
[save](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-save) :

```
  silent: true
```

> If true, the updatedAt timestamp will not be updated.

Comment: Thank you! It works.

Sequelize documenation s****s sometimes